# Floating point not outputting right answer

Tags: assembly, irvine32

I am having two issues with my Assembly code. According to the guidelines, I must do all of this using floating point operation. With that said, it seems like I am not getting the correct answer from this, and I don't know what is wrong. The function is as follows: y=3x^3+2.7x^2-74x+6.3. I have to give X, and it is suppose to go into this function and output Y.

The code is also suppose to end when I type N, but it keeps giving me a floating point error.

EDIT: I figured out my problem with the function, however whenever I type N it doesn't jump down and end my code.

```
input       REAL8 ?         ; user input
result      REAL8 ?         ; result of calculation
three       REAL8 3.0       ; constant
twoSeven    REAL8 2.7       ; constant
seventyFour REAL8 74.0      ; constant
sixThree    REAL8 6.3       ; constant


prompt  BYTE "Enter an Integer or n to quit",0dh,0ah,0
again   BYTE "Would you like to go again? Y/N?", 0dh, 0ah, 0
no      BYTE "N",0dh,0ah,0
rprompt BYTE "The result of the calculation is ",0

.code
main PROC
result_loop:
finit                   ; initialize the floating point stack
mov edx,OFFSET prompt   ; address of message
call WriteString        ; write prompt
call ReadFloat          ; read the input value
fst input               ; save input of user


fmul three             ; multiplies by three
fadd twoSeven          ; Adds by 2.7
fmul input             ; multiplies by the input
fsub seventyFour       ; subtracts 74
fmul input             ; multiplies by input 
fadd sixThree          ; adds by three

fst result              ; puts value in area
mov edx,OFFSET rprompt  ; address of message
call WriteString        ; write prompt
call WriteFloat         ; writes the result
call CrLf               ; prints new line 

mov edx, OFFSET again
call WriteString
Call ReadString

cmp edx, 'n'            ; compares the input to n
je end_if               ; jumps if its equal to n
jmp result_loop         ; jumps back to the top

end_if:                 ; end statment 
call WaitMsg            ; 
exit                    ;
main ENDP
END main
```

Comment: `FCOMI input, 'n'` makes no sense whatsoever. You probably want to read a string, compare that to `"n"`, and if it isn't equal, convert it to float.

Comment: @jester I made a minor tweak to the code, adding input2, and trying to setup the compare between n and the input, however I am still coming up short.

Comment: `'n'` is not a number, you realize that, right? You can not read it as a float.

Comment: Are you really supposed to check for an `'n'` character with FP compares?  If so, I guess you need the ASCII code of `'n'` as a floating-point constant.  Also, you don't seem to `fstp` anywhere, so you'll eventually overflow the FP stack.  I assume ReadFloat pushes the return value onto the FP stack.  Use a debugger to see registers as you single-step your code.

Comment: With that change, are you sure `ReadString` returns a *string* by *value* in a 4-byte register fixed-width?  (And are you sure it's `edx`?  In most calling conventions, return values go in `eax`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
>  Call ReadString
>  cmp edx, 'n'            ; compares the input to n
>  je end_if               ; jumps if its equal to n
>  jmp result_loop         ; jumps back to the top
> end_if:                 ; end statment
> ```

ReadString does not work the way you think it works.

You need to pass it in `EDX` a pointer to a buffer that can store the input. You also need to tell in `ECX` how many characters you can allow this buffer to contain.

When ReadString returns, you'll get in `EAX` the number of characters that were effectively inputted.

So define a buffer and setup the parameters.

Then your code becomes:

```
 mov  edx, offset InBuffer
 mov  ecx, 1
 Call ReadString
 test eax, eax
 jz   result_loop     ; Jump back if no input given!
 mov  al, [edx]       ; Get the only character
 or   al, 32          ; Make LCase to accept 'n' as well as 'N'
 cmp  al, 'n'         ; compares the input to n
 jne  result_loop     ; jumps back if its not equal to n
end_if:               ; end statment
```